# lost in loop foreach

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dynamic menu with sub level but I think I am lost in my loop. I can have the 1st level but after other level has the same name.

What is the modifications that I can applied

Thank you.

```
result :  we can see at the 2bnd level the same name for all 1st level.

    Accueil
        2nd level Administration
        2nd level Index Catalogue
    Catalogue
        2nd level Administration
        2nd level Index Catalogue
    Configuration
        2nd level Administration
        2nd level Index Catalogue



<?php
// Select all entries from the menu table
      $Qmenus = $Db->prepare('SELECT a.id, 
                                            a.link, 
                                            a.parent_id, 
                                            a.class,
                                            a.sort_order,
                                            amd.label 
                                      FROM :table_administrator_menu a,
                                          :table_administrator_menu_description amd
                                      where a.id = amd.id
                                      and amd.language_id = :language_id
                                      ORDER BY a.parent_id, 
                                               a.sort_order
                                      ');

      $Qmenus->bindInt(':language_id', $Language->getId());
      $Qmenus->execute();

      $Qmenus = $Qmenus->fetchAll();
    ?>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
      <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <?php
        foreach ($Qmenus as $menus) {
          if ($menus['parent_id'] == 0) {
    ?>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i><?php echo $menus['label']; ?><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <?php
            foreach ($Qmenus as $menus) {
              if ( $menus['parent_id'] == 1) {
    ?>
              <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">2nd level <?php echo $menus['label']?></a>
                </li>
    <?php
                foreach ($Qmenus as $menus) {
                  if ( $menus['parent_id'] == 2) {
    ?>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
    <?php
                  }
                } // end level 3
    ?>

              </ul>
    <?php
              } //
            } // end level 3
    ?>
            </li>
    <?php
        } // end level 1
      }
    ?>


          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>
```

more information

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [link] => 
            [parent_id] => 0
            [class] => 
            [sort_order] => 1
            [label] => Accueil
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [link] => 
            [parent_id] => 0
            [class] => 
            [sort_order] => 1
            [label] => Catalogue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [link] => 
            [parent_id] => 0
            [class] => 
            [sort_order] => 2
            [label] => Configuration
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [link] => 
            [parent_id] => 1
            [class] => 
            [sort_order] => 1
            [label] => Administration
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [link] => 
            [parent_id] => 1
            [class] => 
            [sort_order] => 2
            [label] => Index Catalogue
        )
```

table administrator_menu

```
 id     parent_id   sort_order  class
    1       0            2  
    3       0            1  
    5       0            3  
    6       0            4  
    7       3            1  
    8       3            2  
    9       1            1  
    10      9            0
```

table description menu

```
 id  lable            language_id
    1   Configuration   1
    1   Configuration   2
    3   Accueil         1
    3   Index           2
    5   Catalogue       1
    5   Catalog         2
    7   Administration  1
    7   Administration  2
    8   Index Catalogue 1
    8   Index Shop      2
    9   Ma boutique     1
    9   My shop         2
    10  Configuration générale  1
    10  general Configuration   2
```

Comment: You're looping tree times same field, why do you do that? Shouldn't there be one loop with `if` checks of `parent_id`..

Comment: Ok, I am beginner, how to do that correctly.

Comment: I would gladly help you, but could you print the full array `Qmenus`. So we can see what do you have, as we arleady know what you want.

Comment: Tk, I inserted inside the code (above) the elements on Qmenus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous examples were didn't do what you expected, so i made new online on **[fiddle, click to see!](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fdaq-kejs)**:

```
$menu_parent = array();
$menu_sub = array();
foreach ($Qmenus as $menus) {
    if ($menus['parent_id']==0) {
        $menu_parent[$menus['id']] = $menus;
        }
    else {
        if (isset($menu_parent[ $menus['parent_id'] ])) {
            $menu_parent[ $menus['parent_id'] ]['sub_menu'][$menus['id']] = $menus['id'];
            $menu_sub[$menus['id']] = $menus;
            }
        else if (isset($menu_sub[ $menus['parent_id'] ])) {
                $menu_sub[ $menus['parent_id'] ]['sub_menu'][$menus['id']] = $menus['id'];
                $menu_sub[$menus['id']] = $menus;
                }
        }
}

foreach($menu_parent as $key => $menus) {
        echo '<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i>'.$menus['label'].'<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>';
        if (!empty($menus['sub_menu'])) {
            echo '<ul class="nav nav-second-level">';
            foreach($menus['sub_menu'] as $second_level) {
                    echo '<li><a href="#">'.$menu_sub[ $second_level ]['label'].'</a>';
                    if (!empty($menu_sub[ $second_level ]['sub_menu'])) {
                        echo '<ul class="nav nav-third-level">';
                        foreach($menu_sub[ $second_level ]['sub_menu'] as $third_level) {
                                echo '<li><a href="#">'.$menu_sub[ $third_level ]['label'].'</a>';
                                if (!empty($menu_sub[ $third_level ]['sub_menu'])) {
                                    echo '<ul class="nav nav-fourth-level">';
                                    foreach($menu_sub[ $third_level ]['sub_menu'] as $fourth_level) {
                                            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$menu_sub[ $fourth_level ]['label'].'</a></li>';
                                            }
                                    echo '</ul>';
                                    }
                                echo '</li>';
                                }
                        echo '</ul>';
                        }

                    echo '</li>';
                    }
            echo '</ul>';
            }
        echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Ok It work, TK, Just a question with 3 or 4 level. it work also, because I need that.

Comment: So how do i understand your `parent_id` represent level of items, i mean first level, second level, third level and so on? Right or ?

Comment: yes exactly, this is the system that I would create

Comment: But your system has the problem, how do you connect 2nd level with first one, or the 3rd with 2nd ? (In array- take a look, how to connect any of them) ? I were thinking `parent_id` represents `id` of menu with `parent_id=0`

Comment: Or you're planing, the array will be always sorted, parent, 2nd level of parent, 3nd level and so on, then again parent, 2nd level of this parent.. and so on?

Comment: If the above is what you're planing, i will modify the code to your needs.

Comment: I write some informations look above the table administrator_menu and administrator_menu_description. Look the Id 10 for example, parent_id is affiliate at id 9. That I want to mean, we are on sublevel 3.

Comment: Ok, just when I actualise the page, I have a weird result. 
for example the second level is write like this : 
9 1 1 M 1 is in relation of parent_id. it's correct but the label is not display: 
the display result:
Configuration

    9
    1
    1
    M
    1

Comment: I found an error : Illegal string offset 'label' and the line is : 
foreach($menu_sub[$menus['sub_menu']  ] as $sub_key => $submenus) {

        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $submenus['label'] . '</a>';

Comment: Do you make a changement ?

Comment: I've made an full-edit, and make you working live example! Best regards and don't forget to vote!